# How to crop a custom shape using Javascript HTML5

Tags: javascript

How can we crop a custom shape from an image using javascript?

Essentially I want the user to be able to crop a face out of a photo.

Something like [www.jibjab.com](http://jibjab.com) , they do it with Flash we need to do it in JS on HTML5 canvas.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

### Try something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  }
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // begin custom shape
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

  // complete custom shape
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. This part I know. Any idea how to crop the image out of the canvas?

Comment: Check this out:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement You can usesomething like the img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

Comment: Also see this example:- http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/crop/ May be that helps you!! :) Happy coding

Comment: @RahulTripathi unfortunately this website was sold, I searched in the repo but I can't find any reference to crop and the documentation doesn't exist